# Adding and removing a class at the same time as updating a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

I am very new to JavaScript. I am trying to update a div, which works fine before the add and remove class pieces are added. The problem is when I add the class I can't seem to get it to be removed when the when the next image is clicked. I have used a remove class option, but it doesn't seem to want to work.

Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
$('[class^="question"]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var numb = this.className.replace('question', '');
  $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
  $('.question*').removeClass('question*selected');
  $('#answer' + numb).show();
  $('.question' + numb).addClass('question' + numb + 'selected');
});
```

[Here is a link](http://jsfiddle.net/c4n2zvsv/) to the Fiddle I am Playing with.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a conditional, checking if class was already added. And $(this) points to the element clicked.

Comment: Please, explain in a better way what the problem is. I've visited the fiddle and I can't understand what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.Besides, there must be missing images or something like that, so the divs are invisible.

Comment: You seem to think that you can just add an asterisk in `removeClass` as a "match all", but that's not how it works, the class must match exactly. Why would you even add numbers to the class in the first place

Comment: The $(this) may work on the clicked one, but I need to remove the Class from the previously clicked one. I want a specific class to be added to the div when a link is clicked on and then I want the same class to be removed when the next link is clicked. There is a different class for each div, so I had hoped to use the * instead of  having to type out code for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of your added class by defining a global variable. I created a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/obPzzw).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var appliedClass = "container1";
   var classNo = 1;

   $(".buttonCon").click(function() {
       if ($(".container").hasClass(appliedClass)) {
           $(".container").removeClass(appliedClass);
           classNo++;
           if (classNo > 4) {classNo = 1;}
           appliedClass = "container" + classNo;
           $(".container").addClass(appliedClass);
       }
   });
 });
```

I have `appliedClass` variable which keeps tracking of the latest added class. Every time you click on the button with `.buttonCon` class, this variable will be updated to the new added class. Next time, first we remove the former class. Then we added the new one. The second `if` statement might not be needed in your case, but in my example, I needed it to keep looping through `container1` to `container4` classes.

Comment: Perfect. This gave me the answer I needed. I just needed to create some extra global variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've set yourself up with a really difficult-to-work-with class structure -- this can be a lot easier than you're making it.  Give each of your "question" links the class 'question' and the unique id "question1", "question2", etc.  Same for the answer nodes: class "answer" and id "answer1", "answer2" etc.

Now you can easily access all question links with `$('.question')` or all answers with `$('.answer')`, and can use the IDs to identify individual nodes as needed:

```
$('.question').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var numb = this.id.replace('question', '');
   var answerNode = $('#answer'+numb);
   if (answerNode.hasClass('hide')) {
     // the Q they clicked on is not yet visible
     $('.answer').addClass('hide');  // hide all answers
     answerNode.removeClass('hide'); // show the desired one
   } else {
     // the Q they clicked on is already visible, so toggle it back off
     answerNode.addClass('hide');
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/647dadtj/